# What can I do with a lone young cardinal I found in my yard?

Tags: birds

A pair of cardinals have nested in my yard for years. Yesterday found a young one in the yard, made it comfortable, just didnt want a cat to get it. Still alive, cant fly. What to do?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in this site; the posts on this site should be about principles of biology. Your question pertains to animal rescue. It is also similar to health advices, which we again consider off-topic. You should contact the local animal rescue/wildlife organization.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/questions-about-wildlife-support-on-the-great-outdoors However, I believe it would require moderator intervention.

Comment: @Alexander Gegg, Another possible site would be cooking.stackexchange.com ;-)